# ffmpegでライブ映像を録画しています。ライブが終了した際には映像が壊れました。

Tags: ffmpeg

現在、以下のcommandでライブ映像を録画ダウンロードしています。

```
ffmpeg -i "EXAMPLE_URL" \
    -c copy -flags +global_header -f segment \
    -segment_time 3600 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart \
    -reset_timestamps 1 "EXAMPLE_%d.mp4"
```

１時間分量でファイルを分けています。
通常は問題ないですが、ライブが終了されると

`ffmpeg last message repeated %N times`が表示されて長時間レスポンスがない状態になります。

このあとCtrl+Cなどで終了すると、その時点の映像が見れなくなります。（おそらく破損）

この問題を回避する方法、もしくはオプションなどがあればお教えていただけますでしょうか。

一番いいのはライブ先が勝手に終了されたら、録画もその時点で正常に終了されるのがベストだと思います。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

> このあとCtrl+Cなどで終了すると、その時点の映像が見れなくなります。

mp4 ではそうなるので、ts で保存しましょう。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。事情があってmp4でやらないといけません。ライブ途中、自らCtrl+Cで終了させるとその映像は見れます。ただライブ先が終了された後にCtrl+Cすると見れなくなります。このへんどうか方法はないでしょうか・・？

Comment: でしたら streamlink でパイプしてみましょう。Youtube live、ニコ生の接続切れを試してみましたが最後の動画は再生できました。
streamlink "EXAMPLE_URL" --default-stream best -o - | ffmpeg -i -  -c copy -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 3600 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 "EXAMPLE_%d.mp4"

Comment: すみません、返事おそくなりました。調べて見るとstreamlinkという別なものが必要とされてますね。今のところ追加ライブラリーの導入は考えておりません。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

試せる「録画するライブ動画のURL」が無いので、`ffmpeg`(v4.0.2, Windows版バイナリ)のオプションを眺めてみると`-timeout`や`-listen_timeout`などのオプションがいくつかあるのを見つけました。

指定出来るのは秒数のようですが、プロトコルによって単位が違ってくるみたいなので環境に合わせてよく確認してみてください。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。やってみましたが変わらずでした。

Answer (score 0):

LinuxもWindowsもコマンドは同じと思います。
windowsのバッチファイルで内部ループして反応しなくなりました。
確か自動終了で検索したとき-audoexit というのがあり、処理が終わると終了です。
バッチファイルを造りffplay で音楽５０曲再生して自動的に終わるようになりました。